# C++ reorder std::vector elements using std::list of pointers

Tags: c++, list, pointers, vector

I ran into this problem when I tried to write out an new algorithm to reorder elements in std::vector. The basic idea is that I have std::list of pointters pointing into std::vector in such way that `*list.begin() == vector[0]`, `*(++list.begin()) == vector[1]` and so on.
However, any modifications on list's element positions breaks the mapping. (Including appended pointers) When the mapping is broken the list's elements can be in random order but they point still into correct elements on vector. The task would be to reorder the elements in vector to correct the mapping.

Simplest method to do it (How I have done it now):

- create new empty std::vector and resize it to equal size of the old vector.
- iterate through the list and read elements from the old vector and write them into new vector. Set the pointer to point into new vector's element.
- swap vectors and release the old vector.

Sadly the method is only useful when I need more capacity on the vector. It's inefficient when the current vector holding the elements has enough capacity to store all incoming elements. Appended pointers on the list will point into diffrent vector's storgate. The simple method works for this because it only reads from the pointers.

So I would want to reorder the vector "in place" using constant amount of memory. Any pointer that was not pointing into current vector's storgate are moved to point into current vector's storgate. Elements are simple structures. (PODs)
I'll try post an example code when I have time..

What should I do to achieve this? I have the basic idea done, but I'm not sure if it is even possible to do the reordering with constant amount of memory.

---

PS: I'm sorry for the (possibly) bad grammar and typos in the post. I hope it's still readable. :)

Comment: It sounds like you're using incorrect data structures for your use case. Why not just use a vector outright?

Comment: I have to store the elements in continous memory.

Answer (score 2):

First off, why do you have a list of pointers? You might as well keep indices into the vector, which you can compute as `std::distance(&v[0], *list_iter)`. So, let's build a vector of indices first, but you can easily adapt that to use your list directly:

```
std::vector<T> v;        // your data
std::list<T*> perm_list; // your given permutation list
std::vector<size_t> perms;

perms.reserve(v.size());
for (std::list<T*>::const_iterator it = perm_list.begin(), end = perm_list.end(); it != end; ++it)
{
  perms.push_back(std::distance(&v[0], *it));
}
```

(There's probably a way to use `std::transform` and `std::bind`, or lambdas, to do this in one line.)

Now to do the work. We simply use the cycle-decomposition of the permutation, and we modify the `perms` vector as we go along:

```
std::set<size_t> done;

for (size_t i = 0; i < perms.size(); while(done.count(++i)) {})
{
  T tmp1 = v[i];
  for (size_t j = perms[i]; j != i; j = perms[j])
  {
    T tmp2 = v[j];
    v[j] = tmp1;
    tmp1 = tmp2;

    done.insert(j);
  }
  v[i] = tmp1;
}
```

I'm using the auxiliary set `done` to track which indices have already been permuted. In C++0x you would add `std::move` everywhere to make this work with movable containers.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I was almost certain that question: "why do you have list of pointters", would be asked. :) The list elements that I realy use aren't just pointers and I use a special member functions to gain the pointers to vector's storgate so I simplified the case.
Does it work if some of the `perm_list` elements do not point into `v`'s storgate? Also This method uses (temporaly but still) twice more memory than my current version. `perms` can be opted out as you said, but it seems I'm forced to use `set`

Comment: You'll somehow need to obtain the index in the vector from your list, one way or another, but I'm sure you can find a way to do that. You could get away without the set if you preprocessed your permutation into cycles and then applied the above algorithm for each cycle separately -- as you can see, the set is only needed to advance `i`, which you could avoid if you work cycle by cycle.